# @supports property syntax error

Tags: css

I was checking the @supports property and it worked for this code -

```
@supports(display: block) {
    .message{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

here it is giving red background but the following code doesn't work

```
.message{
    background: green;
    @supports(display: block){
        background: red;
    }    
}
```

in this case the background should be red but it is coming out green. I have checked this on chrome edge and even on  [codepen](https://codepen.io/KsangwanA/pen/PKrZXW). What is the problem ?

Comment: Typo there.  And we assume you are using SASS?

Comment: CSS does not support nesting like that.

Comment: the examples I checked were working just fine in the second code, what is the typo?

Comment: The second example is malformed. The selector goes inside @supports as in first example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

Comment: https://codepen.io/ramenhog/pen/MpORPa - if you see line 20 of CSS in this pen, then the second code example is also working.

Comment: The [working one](https://codepen.io/ramenhog/pen/MpORPa) is using SCSS. Also, it's spelled "supprots" in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/KsangwanA/pen/PKrZXW), and "supprts" here in your snippet.

Comment: I tried using SCSS on codepen for this and it is still not working. How can I use the second code example correctly?

Answer (score 0):

At-rules can't be nested within style rules. Wherever you're seeing that nested `@supports` rule working must be using some kind of preprocessor.

Comment: I tried using SCSS in codepen too but still not working.